# Windows Phone 8 device debugging not working

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to make some app connect to WCF service. And everything is working just fine, except debugging on the actual device. It reports TimeOut Exception. I don't have issues working with emulator, everything is ok there.

this is the code from my mainpage:

```
public partial class MainPage: PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceReference1.WCFClient serviceClient = new ServiceReference1.WCFClient();

        serviceClient.LoadExamsAsync("Marco");
        serviceClient.LoadExamsCompleted += serviceClient_LoadExamsCompleted;


    }

    void serviceClient_LoadExamsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.LoadExamsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lls2.ItemsSource = e.Result; // longlistselector
    }
 }
```

from IExams.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExams
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<LoadExamsResult> LoadExams();

}
```

and from Exams.svc.cs:

```
public class ExamsService : IExams
{
    public ExamsDataClassesDataContext data { get; set; }
    public ExamsService()
    {
        data = new ExamsDataClassesDataContext();
    }

    public List<LoadExamsResult> LoadExams(string un)
    {
        return data.LoadExams(un).ToList();
    }
}
```

LinqToSql classes are created automatically, and I call stored procedures from database in Sql Server..

this is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Alex;Initial        Catalog=Ispiti;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="1200"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false    before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the   value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception  information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
         Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
   </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and from my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="basicHttpBinding_IExams" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.137.146:14584/Exams.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IExams" contract="ServiceReference1.IExams"
                name="basicHttpBinding_IExams" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: I've edited the question.. I don't think that there is some issue with the code itself.. but I'm not sure.. I did shrink everything in the code to check if the basic things are going to work, but with no success.

Comment: Are you able to access the service/metadata about it on real device inside browser? I mean to say, whether the service is accessible on device?

Comment: @MayurTendulkar I'm not really sure how to do that, but there definitely a difference when I try to access the service address in emulator and in device IE.. I get the page of the service in emulator, but not in the mobile..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the WCF service on your local computer you need to allow external connections throught the Firewall. Also, you need to have your device connected to the same network of your PC. Even then, you can try to Connect to the service using the PC IP and not the name (use `http://192.168.1.23/service` and not `http://mypcname/service`).

Comment: I already followed instructions from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx , and my computer and my phone are on the same wifi network.

Comment: In this case, any firewall/anti-virus program must be running or blocking the access. Also one case would be the service running on other port. So, as Josue mentioned, address will be http://192.168.1.23:XXXX. You'll also need to make sure that this port is open if firewall/anti-virus.

Comment: I haven't installed any antivirus because it was blocking access to the emulator, I adjusted firewall inbound rule for the port I'm using.. it's something like 192.168.137.146:14584, I even tried to turn off the firewall completely, but with no success. @MayurTendulkar

Comment: I've added listener to web.config file of my service, and in Microsoft Trace Service Viewer I get some exception that says: Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.